# Word dialog shown programmatically doesn't respond to mouse clicks

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, ms-office

The following piece of code shows an *Insert table* dialog:

```
Dialog d = WordApp.Dialogs[WdWordDialog.wdDialogTableInsertTable];
int result = d.Show(ref missing);
if (result == -1)  // if user pressed OK
{
    d.Execute();
}
```

The problem is that the dialog **does not respond** to mouse clicks. It **responds** to keyboard input, though.
Moreover, if I press Alt+Tab (to switch to some other running app) and then press Alt+Tab again (to switch back to my app), it responds to **both** mouse and keyboard input.

My guess is that my application doesn't 'know' that a dialog box was shown (because it doesn't happen in a regular *Form.ShownDialog* way) and it keeps the focus.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with Word 2007. 

What Office version are you using? Do you get the same behavior with all dialogs or only with the insert table dialog?

Comment: Office 2003. 
The Print dialog behaves the same. 
Maybe the problem is caused by something happening in the code (I am maintaining an app I did not create).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out.

I'm not exactly sure why but this helps: **before** displaying the dialog I **disable** the main application form, then **after** the dialog is displayed I **enable** it back.

```
Dialog d = WordApp.Dialogs[WdWordDialog.wdDialogTableInsertTable];

MainApplicationFormInstance.Enabled = false;
int result = d.Display(ref missing);
MainApplicationFormInstance.Enabled = true;

if (result == -1)  // user pressed OK
{
    d.Execute();
}
```